# transform array of arrays into arguments for a function in Python

Tags: python

I want to use a function that takes `*args:arrays` as arguments (so `f(a,b,c,...,z)` where `a`,`b`,...`z` are arrays.
I have my variables stored as `array_vars = [a,b,c,...,z]`.

How do I transform array_vars so that the function `f` understands ?

Comment: `f(*array_vars)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `*` operator to unpack the items from a `list`.

```
f(*array_vars)
```

**Example**

```
>>> def f(*args):
...     for x in args:
...         print(x)
... 
>>> f(1, 2, 3)
1
2
3
>>> f(*[1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

With * you can unpack arguments from a list or tuple and ** unpacks arguments from a dict.

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```